# Read a text file and count the number of white spaces in the text file

Tags: java, whitespace

I need my program in Java to get a text file, read that text file, count and reproduce the amount of white spaces in that text file

Here is the code I currently have

```java
import java.io.File;  //import the file class
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; //import this class to handle errors
import java.util.Scanner; //import the scanner class to read the file

public class whitespaceReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            File myFile = new File("aliceInWonderland.txt");

            Scanner reader = new Scanner(myFile);

            int space = 0;
            int i = 0;
            String word;

            word = reader.nextLine();

            while (i < word.length()){
                char a = word.charAt(i);

                if(a == '//tried to use empty brackets here, did not work') {
                    space++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println("amount of white space is: " + space);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print("Uh oh! Something went wrong");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read the assignment requirements carefully to understand exactly what your teacher means by "white spaces".  Does it mean just the `SP` character?  What about `TAB` (aka `HT`) or `VT`?  What about `CR` and `NL`?  What about non-breaking space codes?   Also, find out if a `TAB` means exactly one "white space", and if `CR` `NL` means one "white space" or two.

Comment: But if you **only** need to count `SP` characters, then `a == ' '` will do.  Precisely one space character between the (single) quotes.

Comment: the assignment requirements don't specify any of those definitions, it literally just says count white space. I assumed it meant between the words? But there's little detail.

Comment: Then you need to **>>ask<<** your teacher what he or she means.  Or make a guess and hope that you guessed correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. I will clarify with the tutour and your advice was very helpful with the one space character between the single quotes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        File myFile = new File("aliceInWonderland.txt");

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(myFile);

        int space = 0;
        int n = 0;
        String word = "";

        while(reader.hasNextLine()){
            word += reader.nextLine();
        }
        n = word.length();

        space = word.replace(" ","").length();
        space = n - space;
        System.out.println("amount of white space is: " + space);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.print("Uh oh! Something went wrong");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You just need to subtract the length of the sentence with the length of the sentence without whitespaces.

No need for loops

Answer (score 0):

Use BufferedReader to readLines like this.

```java
final String fileName = "Path to your file"
final char countedChar = ' ';
int characterCount = 0;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
 for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
   if(countedChar == line.charAt(i)){
     characterCount++;
   }
 }
}
System.out.println(characterCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class `java.util.Scanner` and you are counting only the space characters, i.e. the character whose Unicode code point is 32 (decimal), and you are using at least JDK 9, then you can simply call method [findAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findAll-java.lang.String-) and count the number of elements in the stream returned by that method.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhitespaceReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("aliceInWonderland.txt");
        try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(path)) {
            long space = reader.findAll(" ")
                               .count();
            System.out.println("amount of white space is: " + space);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the above code uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that the `Scanner` is closed so as to prevent resource leaks.

Also note that I changed the class name to `WhitespaceReader` so as to adhere to [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

If you want to count all [whitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-) characters, simply change the string argument (to method `findAll`) to `\\s+`. Refer to *javadoc* for class [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.nio.file.Files;
   import java.nio.file.Paths;
    
    public class NumberOfSpacesInAFile {
    
        public static long noOfSpaces = 0;
        
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            
            Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt"))
             .map(lines->{noOfSpaces = noOfSpaces + lines.chars().filter(eachChar->eachChar==32).count();return lines;})
             .count();
            
            System.out.println(noOfSpaces);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).